# Convert GroupBy Object to Ordered List in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 2.0.0 and dataframe.
Here is my input dataframe as

```
| id | year        | qty    |
|----|-------------|--------|
| a  | 2012        | 10     |
| b  | 2012        | 12     |
| c  | 2013        | 5      |
| b  | 2014        | 7      |
| c  | 2012        | 3      |
```

What I want is

```
| id | year_2012 | year_2013 | year_2014 |
|----|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| a  | 10        | 0         | 0         |
| b  | 12        | 0         | 7         |
| c  | 3         | 5         | 0         |
```

or

```
| id | yearly_qty  |
|----|---------------|
| a  | [10, 0, 0]    |
| b  | [12, 0, 7]    |
| c  | [3, 5, 0]     |
```

The closest solution I found is `collect_list()` but this function doesn't provide order for the list. In my mind the solution should be like:

```
data.groupBy('id').agg(collect_function)
```

Is there a way to generate this without filtering every id out using a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one can be easily achieved using `pivot`:

```
from itertools import chain

years = sorted(chain(*df.select("year").distinct().collect()))
df.groupBy("id").pivot("year", years).sum("qty")
```

which can be further converted to array form:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, col

(...
    .na.fill(0)
    .select("id",  array(*[col(str(x)) for x in years]).alias("yearly_qty")))
```

Obtaining the second one directly is probably not worth all the fuss since you'd have to fill the blanks first. Nevertheless you could try:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, struct, sort_array, broadcast
years_df = sc.parallelize([(x, ) for x in years], 1).toDF(["year"])

(broadcast(years_df)
    .join(df.select("id").distinct())
    .join(df, ["year", "id"], "leftouter")
    .na.fill(0)
    .groupBy("id")
    .agg(sort_array(collect_list(struct("year", "qty"))).qty.alias("qty")))
```

It also requires Spark 2.0+ to get a support for `struct` collecting.

Both methods are quite expensive so you should be careful when using these. As a rule of thumb long is better than wide.

Comment: Thanks, `pivot` is what I'm looking for!

Comment: `struct` collecting in pyspark you mean ?

Comment: @eliash `collect_*` in Spark doesn't supports only atomics in Spark < 2.0.